# Wso2 identity server samlsso endpoint 405 error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure wso2 identity server(5.7.0) with my wso2 api manager (2.6.0) for saml2. When I try to browse the identity server admin endpoint I am redirected  to endpoint https://<>:9444/samlsso. 
I am getting an error Error 405 - Method Not Allowed
The network error on chrome browser is GET https://<>:9444/favicon.ico 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: it is not clear what you are doing with SAML2

Comment: I am trying to configure SSO with Saml2 . I am following the instructions in the below link https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2. I am trying to integrate with AWS IDP  so configured api manager for sso and then was configuring external identity with identity server. I get this error when I try to launch the https://<hostname>:9444/carbon

Comment: @Gayan I am trying to configure SSO with Saml2 . I am following the instructions in the below link https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2. I am trying to integrate with AWS IDP  so configured api manager for sso and then was configuring external identity with identity server. I get this error when I try to launch the https://<hostname>:9444/carbon

Comment: Did you try to configure SSO between the API Manager's and Identitiy Server's management consoles ?

Comment: @Gayan  As I have mentioned after following the steps in the link and starting the api manager and identity server , i am not able to open any management console. If I try opening the pages I get redirected to the endpoint  https://<>:9444/samlsso with the Error 405 - Method Not Allowed The network error on chrome browser is GET https://<>:9444/favicon.ico 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Before configuring the api manager for sso  I was able to open api manager management console

Answer (score 0):

You may try to enable SSO for Identity Server management console by modifying `<IS_HOME>`/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml. When you try to login to Identity Server management console it will send SAML Auth request to SAML SSO URL define in authenticators.xml -> IdentityProviderSSOServiceURL. Due to some reason IdentityProviderSSOServiceURL is not accessible. You can please check on availability of  https://<>:9444/samlsso.

Comment: Hi Gayan. Thanks .  When i inspect the browser, the network error that I see  is, it is trying to run a GET on the link https://<hostname>:9444/favicon.ico. The result is error 405 method not found. Does it give any clue.  Additionally I have changed the host name.